# PDF generation by Phantomjs adding additonal gray bars

Tags: php, pdf, highcharts, phantomjs

**Question**: PDF generated by Phantomjs has additional grey bars coming in the Graph.

**Set up**: My Front end is using highcharts to create graphs for the pages. 
           I have used phantomjs to create PDF from the HTML page.

**Sample**: [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPO2E.png)

**My Attempts**: Followed numerous posts and answers to the same topic and gave the following tries but unsuccessful.

1. **Disable animation and enableMouseTracking for whole chart**.

   $('#graph').highcharts({
               chart: {
                   type: 'bar',
                   animation: false,
                   enableMouseTracking: false
               },
2. **Disable animation and enableMouseTracking in PlotOptions**:

   plotOptions: {
                   bar: {
                       animation: false,
                       enableMouseTracking: false
                   },
                   series: {
                       stacking: 'normal',
                       animation: false,
                       enableMouseTracking: false,
                       shadow:false
3. **Disabling tool tip**:

   tooltip: {
                   enabled: false
               },

`$('#graph').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    animation: false,
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Online Survey Results'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: data
                },
               yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: maxTotalAnswerWeight,
                    tickInterval: Math.round(tickInterval),
                    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                    minorTickInterval: Math.round(tickInterval),
                    minorTickLength: 10,
                    minorTickWidth: 1,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Progress'
                    },
                    labels: {
                       enabled: true,
                       align: 'right',
                       rotation: -45,
                       formatter: function() {
                           //console.log(this.value)
                           var tickMarkNumber = this.value/Math.round(tickInterval);
                           return seriesData[tickMarkNumber]
                       },
                       style: {
                           fontSize: '14px',
                           fontFamily: 'proxima-nova,helvetica,arial,sans-seri',
                           /*whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                           paddingLeft: 50,
                           paddingRight: '100px',
                           marginLeft: "50px",
                           padding: 10,
                           paddingBottom: '10px'*/
                       }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    reversed: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        animation: false,
                        enableMouseTracking: false
                    },
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        animation: false,
                        enableMouseTracking: false,
                        shadow:false
                        /*dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                            style: {
                                textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                            }
                        }*/
                    }
                },
                colors: ['green','gray'],
                series: [{
                    index: 1,
                    name: 'Progress made',
                    data: achievedData
                }, {
                    index: 0,
                    name: 'Progress yet to be made',
                    data: yetToAchievedData
                }]
            });
        },`

Is there anything very fundamental I am missing here?

Comment: Your code has **MANY** syntax errors (copied and pasted to IDE to understand), can you provide the *full* sample code so that we can have the full picture?

Comment: Hi Sam, i have added the whole highcharts function...

Comment: Right now, what you need to disable, vertical gray lines or something different, because Im confused.

Comment: @SebastianBochan: Thanks for your time. Looking at image i attached , you can see some extra vertical bars coming. horizontal ones (green/grey) are fine but i need to get rid of vertical bars.

Comment: Set [gridLineWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.gridLineWidth) on yAxis as 0.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBochan: Sorry got busy with project related stuff do couldn't follow up the trail....i added your suggestion but still no effect. Please check if i have added it correctly.                                                           max: maxTotalAnswerWeight,
                    tickInterval: Math.round(tickInterval),
                    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    minorTickInterval: Math.round(tickInterval),
                    minorTickLength: 10,
                    minorTickWidth: 1,
                    lineWidth: 1,

Comment: Please recreate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net.